# Generate N random and unique numbers within a range

Tags: c#, .net, random, unique

What is an efficient way of generating N unique numbers within a given range using C#? For example, generate 6 unique numbers between 1 and 50. A lazy way would be to simply use `Random.Next()` in a loop and store that number in an array/list, then repeat and check if it already exists or not etc.. Is there a better way to generate a group of random, but unique, numbers? 
To add more context, I would like to select N random items from a collection, using their index.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Five unique, random numbers from a subset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003192/five-unique-random-numbers-from-a-subset)

Comment: @drachenstern: Bit touchy today aren't we? @Tim - Sorry, I didn't search for 'subset' keyword and ended up with results for why random number generation is hard. Thanks for the link.

Comment: ~ I don't think so. I think this problem is well solved. Somebody else apparently agrees with me.

Comment: @drachenstern - Nothing to do with what you were saying. Just wondering if sarcasm was really required.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take an array of 50 elements: `{1, 2, 3, .... 50}` 
Shuffle the array using any of the standard algorithms of randomly shuffling arrays. The first six elements of the modified array is what you are looking for. HTH

Comment: @HPT: Naturally in that case it is better to keep a set of already had numbers. But in this case, when the numbers are small, I believe my solution is not bad at all

Comment: @armen: Correct solution is something and good solution is another thing. you can write a random generator as question mentioned for this problem too! but that could not be the solution.

Comment: @HPT: At least my solution has predictable runtime

Comment: @at least O(n) memory usage and O(n) runtime! n : indicates the range

Comment: This solution may be okay for 6-from-50 since random-sorting 50 items may not not be a killer. But, then again, so is the simplistic remember-and-throw-away-duplicates method since the chances of duplicates is not high. For a more efficient answer (no upfront sorting, guaranteed no duplicates), you want Fisher-Yates shuffle as per my answer but that _may_ not actually be necessary here - you have to target your solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 11):

For 6-from-50, I'm not too sure I'd worry about efficiency since the chance of a duplicate is relatively low (30% overall, from my back-of-the-envelope calculations). You could quite easily just remember the previous numbers you'd generated and throw them away, something like (pseudo-code):

```
n[0] = rnd(50)
for each i in 1..5:
    n[i] = n[0]
while n[1] == n[0]:
    n[1] = rnd(50)
while n[2] == any of (n[0], n[1]):
    n[2] = rnd(50)
while n[3] == any of (n[0], n[1], n[2]):
    n[3] = rnd(50)
while n[4] == any of (n[0], n[1], n[2], n[3]):
    n[4] = rnd(50)
while n[5] == any of (n[0], n[1], n[2], n[3], n[4]):
    n[5] = rnd(50)
```

However, this will break down as you move from 6-from-50 to 48-from-50, or 6-from-6, since the duplicates start getting *far* more probable. That's because the pool of available numbers gets smaller and you end up throwing away more and more.

For a very efficient solution that gives you a subset of your values with *zero* possibility of duplicates (and no unnecessary up-front sorting), Fisher-Yates is the way to go.

```
dim n[50]                 // gives n[0] through n[9]
for each i in 0..49:
    n[i] = i              // initialise them to their indexes
nsize = 50                // starting pool size
do 6 times:
    i = rnd(nsize)        // give a number between 0 and nsize-1
    print n[i]
    nsize = nsize - 1     // these two lines effectively remove the used number
    n[i] = n[nsize]
```

By simply selecting a random number from the pool, replacing it with the top number from that pool, then reducing the size of the pool, you get a shuffle without having to worry about a large number of swaps up front.

This is important if the number is high in that it doesn't introduce an unnecessary startup delay.

For example, examine the following bench-check, choosing 10-from-10:

```
<------ n[] ------>
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  nsize  rnd(nsize)  output
-------------------  -----  ----------  ------
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9     10           4       4
0 1 2 3 9 5 6 7 8        9           7       7
0 1 2 3 9 5 6 8          8           2       2
0 1 8 3 9 5 6            7           6       6
0 1 8 3 9 5              6           0       0
5 1 8 3 9                5           2       8
5 1 9 3                  4           1       1
5 3 9                    3           0       5
9 3                      2           1       3
9                        1           0       9
```

You can see the pool reducing as you go and, because you're always replacing the used one with an unused one, you'll never have a repeat.

Using the results returned from that as indexes into your collection will guarantee that no duplicate items will be selected.

Comment: This is the best solution, an improved version of mine.

Comment: Storing all numbers in memory may be impossible if the range is huge

Answer (score 8):

```
var random = new Random();
var intArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).OrderBy(t => random.Next()).ToArray();
```

This array will contain 5 random numbers from 0 to 4.

or

```
  var intArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).OrderBy(t => random.Next()).Take(5).ToArray();
```

This array will contain 5 random numbers between 0 to 10.

```
int firstNumber = intArray[0];
int secondNumber = intArray[1];
int thirdNumber = intArray[2];
int fourthNumber = intArray[3];
int fifthNumber = intArray[4];
```

Comment: First one is a very neat solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

For large sets of unique numbers, put them in an List..

```
        Random random = new Random();
        List<int> uniqueInts = new List<int>(10000);
        List<int> ranInts = new List<int>(500);
        for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) { uniqueInts.Add(i); }

        for (int i = 1; i < 500; i++)
        {
            int index = random.Next(uniqueInts.Count) + 1;
            ranInts.Add(uniqueInts[index]);
            uniqueInts.RemoveAt(index);
        }
```

Then randomly generate a number from 1 to myInts.Count.  Store the `myInt` value and remove it from the List.  No need to shuffle the list nor look to see if the value already exists.

Comment: Removing the number from the List (whatever `IEnumerable` you want to use) makes it unique, you can't get it from the list if it doesn't exist...  Again this is faster for LARGE sets of unique numbers, because you are not looking for a number that may or may not exist.

Comment: works great for me. Just one minor bug: it should be uniqueInts.RemoveAt(index); instead of uniqueInts.Remove(index);

Comment: @AyKarsi, That is an extremely important note, thanks! (Updated)

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `List` use `Dictionary`!!

Comment: also you should check to add N successful add, It's obvious how to check whether you have added a new value to dictionary or not!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I guess dictionaries would be better for larger sets.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone else, I prefer allocating the minimum number of items necessary.  Below, I make use of a HashSet, which ensures that new items are unique.  This should work with very large collections as well, up to the limits of what HashSet plays nice with.

```
    public static IEnumerable<int> GetRandomNumbers(int numValues, int maxVal)
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        var yieldedValues = new HashSet<int>();

        int counter = 0;
        while (counter < numValues)
        {
            var r = rand.Next(maxVal);
            if (yieldedValues.Add(r))
            {
                counter++;
                yield return r;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

generate unique random nos from 1 to 40 :

output confirmed :

```
class Program

{
    static int[] a = new int[40];
    static Random r = new Random();
    static bool b;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int t;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
        lab:  t = r.Next(1, 40);
            for(int j=0;j<20;j++)
            {

                if (a[j] == t)
                {
                    goto lab;
                }
            }

            a[i] = t;
            Console.WriteLine(a[i]);



        }
        Console.Read();
    }


}
```

sample output :

7
38
14
18
13
29
28
26
22
8
24
19
35
39
33
32
20
2
15
37

Comment: Dreadfully inefficient solution... especially when there have been much better answers already presented. You also got unused properties and you used Goto!!! Why?