# Using a Recursive Loop and Integer Array for Non-Repeating Random Numbers

Tags: c#

I realize that using random does not generate truly random numbers, but I do not understand why this code shouldn't work to prevent repetition. The goal is to derive 8 unique numbers from between (and not including) 0 and 44. There aren't any errors in running the code, but repeats do occur:

```
//Loop Begins Within Main
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    //Begins Recursion
    int x = Unique8(rndm, num8);
    num8[i] = x;
}

//Recursion Takes Place Outside of the Main with Static Declarations
static Random rndm = new Random();
static int[] num8 = new int[8];

static int Unique8 (Random rndm, int[] num8)
{
    int x = rndm.Next(1, 43);

    //Seeks if Number is Repeated
    if (num8.Contains(x))
    {
        //If So, Recursion Takes Place
        Unique8(rndm, num8);
    }

    //Returns Value to Original Loop to be Assigned to Array
    return x;
}
```

If Random is regenerating numbers because of an algorithm, why are they passing through the recursion? Why doesn't this become an endless loop?

I've found a good solution to this, akin to the shuffling of a deck and drawing cards off of the top. Creating the original sorted array is easy, but I don't understand how it is 'shuffled'. How do you disorder an array in C#

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate N random and unique numbers within a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299138/generate-n-random-and-unique-numbers-within-a-range)

Comment: This is a bad way to do it because it is unbounded. There is no guarantee that it will ever terminate.

Answer (score 9):

See

```
 //If So, Recursion Takes Place
 Unique8(rndm, num8);
```

You're not doing anything with the return value - you <strike>should</strike> could change this to

```
 x = Unique8(rndm, num8);
```

Comment: Or even return Unique8(rndm, num8)

Answer (score 3):

If you are unlucky, your code may result in *stackoverflow*. Here is another way of getting 8 unique numbers using shuffling.

```
int[] array = new int[43];
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) array[i] = i+1;

FisherYatesShuffle(array);

int[] newArray = array.Take(8).ToArray();
```

---

```
public static void FisherYatesShuffle<T>(T[] array)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = array.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int j = r.Next(0, i + 1);
        T temp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the Fisher Yates shuffle as L.B has already posted. Another way I've done it in the past is to populate a list with all your possible values and then randomly draw from that list by generating a random number between 0 and the list count. Then use List.RemoveAt to remove the number you just drew:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>(43);
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) myList.Add(i+1);


for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
{
    int idx = rndm.Next(myList.Count);
    num8[i] = myList[idx];
    myList.RemoveAt(idx);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this essentially do exactly the same as `return rndm.Next(myList.Count);`?

Comment: @sji: No, it doesn't. You have to remove the items you've used from the list to ensure you don't get them again.