# Random number generator as unique all of

Tags: c#, algorithm, random

I'm busy in C# and I try to generate unique values between 0-256.I use the arraylist for this.array is a arraylist

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
      array.Add(i);

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                x = rand.Next(0, m);
                dizi_random[i] = (int)array[x];               
                array.Remove(x);               
                m--;
            }
```

But I didn't generate unique values.What can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate N random and unique numbers within a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299138/generate-n-random-and-unique-numbers-within-a-range)

Answer (score 4):

It can instead be done rather concisely using Linq; generate a range and sort it randomly;

```
Random rand = new Random((int)DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);

var randomArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 256).OrderBy(_ => rand.NextDouble());
```

Comment: Your seeding is even worse than what `new Random()` uses, and that says something.