# Generate a Unique 6 digit number from set of 0-49 such that no two numbers repeat?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm given a set {0,1,2,....49}.
I have to generate a set of numbers(1 or 2 digit) such that no two numbers in it repeat
ex

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

or

```
1 23 32 8
```

Here 2 is repeating but 2 digit num '23' or '32' is not.
This is where im getting stuck.
I tried [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299138/generate-n-random-and-unique-numbers-within-a-range). But could not find solution.
Please help.

**Edit**: Sorry for the unclear explaination before.
this is 1 time generation and i want to generate all such possible numbers.

Comment: what is the problem with the solution you linked?

Comment: Can you provide code you tried. And desribe your troubles more specific?

Comment: You need to decide whether you're looking for "6 digits" or "some collection of numbers, whose total number of digits is 6". For example, what's to stop you from just shuffling the 10 digits (0..9) and then picking the first 6? No need for the "set of 0-49" at all.

Comment: You mention the word "unique" in the title, what does that word mean in this context? That every time you generate a new number you need one that hasn't been seen before?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example for the question you asked. hope that it will help you. i think there is no need for line by line explanation for code since the code speak for itself.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
string output="";
List<int> numbersTaken = new List<int>(); 
int curNumber;
while (output.Length < 6)
  {
    Label:      curNumber = rnd.Next(0, 49);
    if (!numbersTaken.Contains(curNumber) && output.Length + curNumber.ToString().Length <= 6)
       {
          output += curNumber;
          numbersTaken.Add(curNumber);
       }
    else
       {
          if (output.Length <= 6) { return; }
          goto Label;
       }                
  }
```

**Updates:** 
In particular point of execution, Let the output be `output="12451"` and the `curNumber=33`, so it is clear that `33` is not yet taken but if we add `33` to the output then the length of `output` exceed the limit`6` so we have to look for another random number(`goto` redirect to the next random number) which is not present in the string.

Comment: please add an explanation of what you did there. some parts of your code make no sense to me.

Comment: i think there is no need for line by line explanation for code since the code speak for itself.

Comment: you didnt not get my point. the `label:` and the respective `goto` serve no purpose where they are now. the `while` loop will do the same anyway.

Comment: @banana: absolutely not. there may be chance for getting string of length `7` if it is not there