# Need to generate pair of numbers from a given range in C#

Tags: c#, random

Well, I need to generate 2 numbers within the range of (1,8).
Suppose, The first two numbers are 3 & 4. In second time the range will exclude 3 & 4, that's what i want to accomplish. In this way the loop will continue for 4 times.

I have been trying it...but cannot proceed
All I know is to use `Random` Class

**The range is fixed**

Any type of help will be accepted.Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4299138/121309

Comment: Use random to pick from a list, and remove the items picked from the list before you pick the second time. look at https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/parker/sampling/repl.htm

Comment: Assuming that 3 and 4 are just examples, `Enumerable.Range(1,8)`, shuffle them, put them into a stack and pop them as you need them

Comment: Can you please share the code...it would be very helpful@Plutonix @Charles Bretana

Answer (score 4):

**Approach 1 (Classical):**

```
static List<Tuple<int, int>> GetPairs(int min, int max, Random r)
{
    var items = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
    var pickedItems = new HashSet<int>();
    int count = (max - min + 1);

    Func<int> randAndCheck = () =>
    {
        int? candidate = null;

        while(candidate == null || pickedItems.Contains(candidate.Value))
            candidate = r.Next(min, max + 1);

        pickedItems.Add(candidate.Value);
        return candidate.Value;
    };

    while (pickedItems.Count != count)
    {
        int firstItem = randAndCheck();
        int secondItem = randAndCheck();

        items.Add(Tuple.Create(firstItem, secondItem));
    }

    return items;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach(var pair in GetPairs(1, 8, new Random()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"One: {pair.Item1} Two: {pair.Item2}");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
One: 4 Two: 2
One: 8 Two: 3
One: 5 Two: 1
One: 7 Two: 6
```

**Approach 2 with somehow random ordering and differed execution:**

```
static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> TwoAtATime(int min, int max, Random r)
{
    var enumerator = Enumerable.Range(min, max - min + 1)
                                .OrderBy(x=> r.Next()).GetEnumerator();

    while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        int item1 = enumerator.Current;
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            int item2 = enumerator.Current;
            yield return Tuple.Create(item1, item2);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach(var pair in TwoAtATime(1, 8, new Random()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"One: {pair.Item1} Two: {pair.Item2}");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
One: 2 Two: 5
One: 4 Two: 7
One: 1 Two: 6
One: 8 Two: 3
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299138/generate-n-random-and-unique-numbers-within-a-range/18055921#18055921

This served my purpose@user3185569

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly Random rand = 
            new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pickList = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
            while (pickList.Count > 1)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(
                  "Hit any key to get Random pair of integers from List.");
               Console.ReadLine();
               var pair = GetPairFromList(pickList);
               Console.WriteLine($"Pair is: {pair.Item1}: {pair.Item2}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("List is empty; Hit any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static Tuple<int, int> GetPairFromList(IList<int> picks)
        {
            return new Tuple<int, int>(
                GetIntFromList(picks), 
                GetIntFromList(picks));
        }
        private static int GetIntFromList(IList<int> picks)
        {
            // next line is where random picking happens
            var val = picks[(int)(picks.Count*rand.NextDouble())];
            // remove randomly selected item from list
            picks.Remove(val);
            return val;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299138/generate-n-random-and-unique-numbers-within-a-range/18055921#18055921

This served my purpose

Thnks @Charles Bretana

Comment: Then can you mark it as accepted answer?