# How to select a random set of rows?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I select a random set of rows

**The important bits:**

1. I need to specify the number of random rows to select via a variable.
2. Say for instance the number of rows I want to select is 10, then it **HAS TO** select 10 **DIFFERENT** rows. I don't want it to pick out the same row a few times until it has 10.

The code below picks out 1 random row, how can I tailor this to the above spec?

```
<?php $rows = get_field('repeater_field_name');
$row_count = count($rows);
$i = rand(0, $row_count - 1);

echo $rows[$i]['sub_field_name']; ?>
```

Comment: This topic could be useful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003192/five-unique-random-numbers-from-a-subset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    $rows = get_field('repeater_field_name');
    $row_count = count($rows);
    $rand_rows = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < min($row_count, 10); $i++) {
        // Find an index we haven't used already (FYI - this will not scale
        // well for large $row_count...)
        $r = rand(0, $row_count - 1);
        while (array_search($r, $rand_rows) !== false) {
            $r = rand(0, $row_count - 1);
        }
        $rand_rows[] = $r;

        echo $rows[$r]['sub_field_name'];
    }
?>
```

This is a better implementation:

```
<?
$rows_i_want = 10;
$rows = get_field('repeater_field_name');

// Pull out 10 random rows
$rand = array_rand($rows, min(count($rows), $rows_i_want));

// Shuffle the array
shuffle($rand);                                                                                                                     

foreach ($rand as $row) {
    echo $rows[$row]['sub_field_name'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Way better than my answer, the `min` bit is great.

Comment: @SeanBright Thanks, seems like its very close to working. On a few occasions it selected the same row... one time it even selected the same one three times.

Comment: Do you have multiple rows with the same `sub_field_name`?

Comment: @SeanBright Yep I do, there's no way to change that as it's grabbing it from Wordpress.

Comment: I've added a different implementation that I think is better.  I've also corrected the original implementation.

Comment: @SeanBright The second version didn't actually pull in the data. The first version works though, refreshed a tonne of times and all the rows are different. Thanks very much.

Comment: `array_rand` returns an array of keys so it cannot work like this, and it does not handle unique values. I think my solution is simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through the random row process the number of random rows you want to get.

```
<?php
$rows_to_get=10;
$rows = get_field('repeater_field_name');
$row_count = count($rows);
$x=0
while($x<$rows_to_get){
    echo $rows[rand(0, $row_count - 1)]['sub_field_name'];
    $x++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try

```
$rows = get_field('repeater_field_name');
var_dump(__myRand($rows, 10));

function __myRand($rows, $total = 1) {
    $rowCount = count($rows);
    $output = array();
    $x = 0;
    $i = mt_rand(0, $rowCount - 1);

    while ( $x < $total ) {
        if (array_key_exists($i, $output)) {
            $i = mt_rand(0, $rowCount - 1);
        } else {
            $output[$i] = $rows[$i]['sub_field_name'];
            $x ++;
        }
    }
    return $output ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution :

```
$rows = get_field('repeater_field_name');
$limit = 10;

// build new array
$data = array();
foreach ($rows as $r) { $data[] = $r['sub_field_name']; }
shuffle($data);
$data = array_slice($data, 0, min(count($data), $limit));

foreach ($data as $val) {
  // do what you want
  echo $val;
}
```